# Extract SYNONYM and SEQUENCE from Informix metadata

Tags: informix

We are migrating Informix database to oracle. Please help us to extract SYNONYM and SEQUENCE from Informix metadata using query.

Answer (score 5):

Although you don't mention the version of the **informix**, try the ones above.

I believe that since V9.4 there is a system catalog table named [SYSSEQUENCES](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqlr.doc/ids_sqr_067.htm?lang=en) where you can find the information about sequences on each database.

For the synonyms the one to be used is [SYSSYNTABLE](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqlr.doc/ids_sqr_069.htm?lang=en), if you have an older version try the [SYSSYNONYMS](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqlr.doc/ids_sqr_068.htm?lang=en).

Comment: No current version of Informix uses syssynonyms; it is a relic from the days of yore — Informix 1.10, 2.00, 2.10 — and has not been used since version 4.00 (there never was a version 3.00 for various good enough reasons at the time, and the time under discussion is 1986-1988).